# Collection cell removes item on each reloadData() call Swift 5

Tags: uicollectionview, ios13, swift5, xcode11, uicollectionreusableview

Please see below image, that is my correct and initial view.
[image]

But after reloadData() is called for collectionView then it is removing the "COMPLETED" status label, and if I again repeat that action it will remove the "PROCESSING" status label. Does anyone know why it is behaving like this?

[image]

This is my cellForItemAt code.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: DFCollectionViewCellIdentifierConstants.DF_CAPTURED_PANORAMAS_CELL, for: indexPath) as! DFCapturedPanoramasCollectionViewCell
        cell.capturedPanoramasImages.layer.masksToBounds = true
        cell.capturedPanoramasImages.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.capturedPanoramasImages.layer.borderColor = UIColor().hexColor(DFColorConstants.INPUT_TEXT_COLOR).cgColor
        cell.capturedPanoramasImages.layer.cornerRadius = 4

        let url = URL(string:panoramaList[indexPath.item].panoramaThumbnailPath)
        if url != nil && self.panoramaList[indexPath.item].panoramaStatus == DFPanoramaStatusConstants.DF_COMPLETED {
            self.panoramaStatusLabelFunc(cell: cell, index: indexPath.item, bgColor: UIColor().hexColor(DFColorConstants.PANORAMA_STATUS_COMPLETED_COLOR))
            cell.capturedPanoramasImages.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
            {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                cell.capturedPanoramasImages.image = image
            }
            cell.capturedPanoramasLabel.text = panoramaList[indexPath.item].name
        } else if url == nil && self.panoramaList[indexPath.item].panoramaStatus != DFStatusConstants.COMPLETED {
            self.panoramaStatusLabelFunc(cell: cell, index: indexPath.item, bgColor: UIColor().hexColor(DFColorConstants.PANORAMA_STATUS_UPLOADING_AND_PROCESSESING))
            cell.capturedPanoramasImages.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            cell.capturedPanoramasImages.image = self.capturedPanoramasImage[0]
            cell.capturedPanoramasLabel.text = panoramaList[indexPath.item].name
        } else if self.panoramaList[indexPath.item].name == DFStatusConstants.ADD_PANORAMA {
            cell.panoramaStatusLabel.isHidden = true
            cell.capturedPanoramasImages.contentMode = .center
            cell.capturedPanoramasImages.image = self.capturedPanoramasImage[1]
            cell.capturedPanoramasLabel.text = panoramaList[indexPath.item].name
        }
        return cell
    }
```

And panoramaStatusLabelFunc() function.

```
func panoramaStatusLabelFunc(cell: DFCapturedPanoramasCollectionViewCell, index: Int, bgColor: UIColor){
        cell.capturedPanoramasLabel.isHidden = false
        cell.panoramaStatusLabel.layer.backgroundColor = bgColor.cgColor
        cell.panoramaStatusLabel.textColor = UIColor().hexColor(DFColorConstants.TEXT_WHITE_COLOR)
        cell.panoramaStatusLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.panoramaStatusLabel.text = self.panoramaList[index].panoramaStatus
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, it is in below condition with "cell.panoramaStatusLabel.isHidden = true". For some reason it is passing isHidden = true to next cell(I an not sure, but may be beacuse fo Asyn)

```
else if self.panoramaList[indexPath.item].name == DFStatusConstants.ADD_PANORAMA 
{
    cell.panoramaStatusLabel.isHidden = true
    cell.capturedPanoramasImages.contentMode = .center
    cell.capturedPanoramasImages.image = self.capturedPanoramasImage[1]
    cell.capturedPanoramasLabel.text = panoramaList[indexPath.item].name
}
```

To fix I have changed panoramaStatusLabelFunc function as below:

```
    func panoramaStatusLabelFunc(cell: DFCapturedPanoramasCollectionViewCell, index: Int, bgColor: UIColor, isAddHotspot: Bool){
        cell.capturedPanoramasLabel.isHidden = false
        cell.panoramaStatusLabel.layer.backgroundColor = bgColor.cgColor
        cell.panoramaStatusLabel.textColor = UIColor().hexColor(DFColorConstants.TEXT_WHITE_COLOR)
        cell.panoramaStatusLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        if(isAddHotspot) {
            cell.panoramaStatusLabel.text = ""
        } else {
            cell.panoramaStatusLabel.text = self.panoramaList[index].panoramaStatus
        }
    }
```